# Vim: How to synchronize NERDTree with current opened tab file path?

Tags: vim, gvim, nerdtree, vim-plugins

When I open a new tab with different path from the previous file in VIM, NERDTree will still remains the same directory hierarchy of the previous file.

Is there a sync shortcut to change the current root directory to the new opened file's directory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a NERDTree-specific way to do that, but you can always [configure Vim so that it sets the working directory to the current file's directory](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file):

```
autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h
```

Now all what you have to do after opening a file in a new tab is `:NERDTreeToggle` in the new tab itself.

Answer (score 154):

I use the following mapping to view the current buffer in NERDTree:

```
 map <leader>r :NERDTreeFind<cr>
```

Comment: I find this very usefull, and i went to my .vimrc.
I wanted to use some other binding to make it easier to me to remember.
And i found out that there is already a binding for this with NERDTree

`<Leader>f`

Comment: Awesome! Example what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: If you are using this amazing vimrc (not mine), it is mapped to ,nf: https://github.com/amix/vimrc

Comment: What key is `<leader>`?

Comment: @stillanoob, `<leader>` defaults to backslash ```\``` but @alpha_989 and many of us remap it to comma `,` which one can do with `let mapleader = ','` in the .vimrc

Comment: It's funny that I saw this command in NERDTree help like 10 times and didn't bother to read the description for it even once, because the name didn't look like something useful to me: I expected it to do some FS search like UNIX `find(1)`. Turns out it was exactly what I was googling for.

Answer (score 46):

throw a % sign on the end like a boss

`:NERDTree %`

i have this in my .vimrc, it maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to toggle nerdtree in the dir of the current buffer:

`map <C-o> :NERDTreeToggle %<CR>`

Comment: You know I was skeptical. Something in the way you said it :D. But this is the only thing that worked like I needed it to, well done.

Comment: Such a boss answer!

Comment: much boss, such answer

Comment: The only issue is when starting from a blank file, the toggle won't work as there's no dir of the current buffer.

Comment: Ah, saved me two extra key presses, since I was doing `:NERDTree %:h` :)

Answer (score 40):

I found both the existing answers educational, and successfully combined the two so that the behavior is more like many people would expect from an IDE: Click on an open window/buffer, and have that file highlighted in the NERDTree. I put this in my ~/.vimrc:

`autocmd BufEnter * if &modifiable | NERDTreeFind | wincmd p | endif`

What this does:

1. `autocmd BufEnter` - runs every time you focus on a buffer (including the NERDTree window)
2. `if &modifiable` - when you do click the NERDTree window, do nothing else (the NERDTree window is not modifiable)
3. `wincmd p` - NERDTreeFind leaves the cursor focused on the NERDTree; this switches back to the window you'd originally focused on

Note that this won't work on *any* other buffer that isn't modifiable -- but that's generally a good thing; otherwise (for example) any time you got `:help` in vim, NERDTree would find and focus the directory where help files are stored--probably not something you want it to do.

That one-line solution worked great for me at first, but I soon found that it causes NERDTree to activate any time I opened a file--and as a result, it prevents NERDTree from ever being closed! If you don't want to use NERDTree full-time, put this in your .vimrc instead:

```
" returns true iff is NERDTree open/active
function! rc:isNTOpen()        
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

" calls NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! rc:syncTree()
  if &modifiable && rc:isNTOpen() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call rc:syncTree()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `isNTFocused()`? Doesn't the `&modifiable` check cover that case?

Comment: @jrdioko yes, I think you are right, that's a bit redundant. I can't think of any good reason to have that there, and simpler is always better. I'll edit it out, thanks!

Comment: Ran into a lot of issues being unable to navigate windows because of the `wincmd p` (I literally could not get back into certain windows). I ended up doing `let l:curwinnr = winnr()` before `NERDTreeFind` and `exec l:curwnum . "wincmd w"` after it. Solved all the issues.

Comment: `Function name must start with a capital or "s:": rc:isNTOpen()`
Are you using a plugin extending scopes?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know, @BrianHaak. I don't use NerdTree currently, and have misplaced my old `.vimrc` in which I had written that code. I don't recall why I used the `rc:`, but I think it was a namespacing thing to avoid name conflicts with other functions. I wasn't using any plugin specifically related to that, as far as I recall. You'll have to study the docs, or just try leaving it out and see if anything breaks. But I think one of the function names conflicted with something in NerdTree or elsewhere. No one else has asked in almost 5 years, so I have a feeling it's something simple. :)

Comment: @Lambart I just replaced it with `s:`

Comment: @BrianHaak super. I hope it works for you!

Comment: @Lambart I've created a usable config with all problems solved: https://gist.github.com/avesus/1954d9384d86cc1e39cb2b2eff7017b7

Comment: Cool. I've been meaning for years to git-ify my various .rc files. Some day...

Comment: This config works well in most of the cases but it messed up everything when I used coc.nvim go to references functionality. using `BufRead` event in place of the `BufEnter` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question yesterday, after a few hours of digging, I submited a [Pull Request](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/pull/204) to [scrooloose's nerdtree repo](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) introducing a `NERDTreeCWD`command that change NERD tree root to current working directory(Update on 2012-11-12: The PR has been merged into the upstream master,it should be usable on an updated version). With this change, this question can be simply solved by the following code.

```
autocmd BufEnter * silent! if bufname('%') !~# 'NERD_tree_' | cd %:p:h | NERDTreeCWD | wincmd p | endif
```

Compare to @shinzui's and @Lambart's `NERDTreeFind` approach, this does exactly what the question asked. Using `NERDTreeFind` will change the scroll position of the nerdtree and the result are not always the same(If CWD is in NERD tree root, it just simply expands the node instead changing into it).

Compare to @Yaser Sulaiman's answer, this solution alwys have a NERD tree window opened and can be easily codable. If a NERD tree window has already been opened, using `NERDTreeToggle` will need to be fired twice(first close the existing one,then open it again), unfortunately, the second openning will skip the whole cwd processing.

Comment: Doesn't your solution lead to NERDTree always being open?

Also I find that if I use the MRU plugin and try to open files, it opens files in the NERDtree window after I use this change. As it stands this modification will cause a lot of issues and conflicts with MRU (https://github.com/yegappan/mru/wiki/User-Manual), however I don't know why. Maybe other people can check if they have similar issues. I do like that the NERDtree tab is always open..

Comment: Yeah, this results in NERDTree always being open. Sadness.

Comment: To add, you can check if the current buffer is modifiable and only then update the CWD. This is useful in case you use terminal inside neovim (using toggleterm maybe) and you don't want this update CWD to run when you switch to the terminal.

autocmd BufEnter * silent! if bufname('%') !~# 'NERD_tree_' && &modifiable | cd %:p:h | NERDTreeCWD | wincmd p | endif

Answer (score 3):

This behaves like `:NERDTreeToggle` but will show the currently opened file in NERDTree.
If you haven't opened a file yet (i.e., you just entered `vim` in your command line) NERDTree shows `/home`.

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
" Open NERDTree in the directory of the current file (or /home if no file is open)
nmap <silent> <C-i> :call NERDTreeToggleInCurDir()<cr>
function! NERDTreeToggleInCurDir()
  " If NERDTree is open in the current buffer
  if (exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
    exe ":NERDTreeClose"
  else
    exe ":NERDTreeFind"
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: What's `<silent>` key?

Comment: That's not a key, it's [a command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3388/call-a-vim-function-silently).

Comment: Silent just means executed silently. `silent` just prevents things from being echoed.

Answer (score 3):

Check this cool plugin [vim-nerdtree-sync](https://github.com/unkiwii/vim-nerdtree-sync)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin is what you want https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst having the link is nice, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include a bit of context here, and explain what the plugin does, how it should be used, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this could be a good solution for what was asked..

Answer (score 1):

I apply both solutions from [Change current directory using NERDTree](https://superuser.com/q/782350/566300): use `cd` to set the NERDTree working directory to the current directory and `C` to set the NERDTree root node to the current directory

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that Matthias posted to be a great answer with one problem, it doesn't work well in a couple of edge cases.  It works a little better with the change below:

```
function! NERDTreeToggleInCurDir()
  " If NERDTree is open in the current buffer
  if (exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
    exe ":NERDTreeClose"
  elseif bufname('%')
    exe ":NERDTreeFind"
  else
    exe ":NERDTreeCWD"
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improved version of @weynhamz 's answer that syncs NERDTree without leaving it open and also handles read-only and empty buffers:

```
" autocommands that call SyncNerdTree() when the buffer is changed or written
" to
augroup nerd_tree_sync_current_dir
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * call SyncNERDTree()
  autocmd BufWrite * call SyncNERDTree()
augroup end

" sync NERDTree with the current file open
function SyncNERDTree()
  " make sure the buffer isn't a NERDTree buffer, it is not empty, and also
  " make sure the buffer contains a file
  " file
  if stridx(bufname('%'), 'NERD_tree_') == -1 && bufname() != "" && &buftype == "" && &filetype != "" 
    cd %:p:h
    " open a new NERDTree buffer and close it
    NERDTree
    NERDTreeClose
  endif
endfunction
```