# Change current directory using NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

How can I navigate to a file or folder in NERDTree and change the working directory to that folder (or the folder containining the file I'm on).

I know it's possible to keep NERDTree in sync with the NERDTree root ([nerdtree and current directory](https://superuser.com/questions/275760/nerdtree-and-current-directory)), but I'm looking for a macro or something that would change the folder without having any impact on NERDTree itself.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're looking for the `cd` mapping. Type this inside the NERDTree sidebar, and the current directory will be changed to the current entry's. See `:help NERDTree-cd`.

Comment: `Sorry, no help for NERDTree-cd`

Comment: @Jonathon Here it is: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/9310f91476a94ee9c2f3a587171893743a343e26/doc/NERDTree.txt#L557-L562 You may have to run `:helptags`.

Answer (score 24):

If you're inside the NERDTree buffer you can select the folder and press `C` to change the NERDTree root directory. Just type `:help NERDTreeMenu` and go to line 252 typing `252G` or `252gg` to check it yourself.

Comment: This is a capital 'C'.

Answer (score 4):

Press "t" when the cursor is on the folder, it will switch to a new buffer with the nerdtree in the subfolder you have selected